# Как найти свои удалённые сообщения?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, поиск

Как известно, на сайте работает автоудаление сообщений.
Как найти свои вопросы, которые были удалены таким образом?

Comment: А в "недавно удалённых" они не светятся?

Comment: по своим удаленным можно искать, кроме этого они выводятся в списке ответов

Comment: @AK, а я не знаю, насколько недавно.

Comment: @Grundy, подробнее. Что написать, чтобы увидеть, к примеру, все удалённые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать поиск по строке [`deleted:1`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Deleted%3A1)

Comment: Кажется, выяснилось, что работает только от 10К репутации?

Answer (score 3):

Для поиска удаленных ответов/сообщений нужно использовать статус:

```
deleted: yes|no
```

Стоит обратить внимание на предупреждение:

> Примечание: при поиске удалённых сообщений отображаются только ваши сообщения.

Например:

```
user:186999 deleted:yes
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: странно... не работает; показывает все сообщения подряд, будто бы нету этого фильтра, https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFf8M.png

Comment: @mymedia, возможно нужно нажать кнопку _поиск_ :-)

Comment: не, оно не решает проблемку, к тому же на снимке видно, что открыта страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A183314+deleted%3Ayes (и в заголовке указан поисковой запрос)

Comment: @mymedia, забавно, судя по всему дело в репутации. Обрати внимание, в справке справа у тебя статусы заканчиваются на `wiki`. Вероятно при достижении 10000 репутации (возможность видеть удаленные посты) появляется и возможность их искать

Comment: @mymedia оказывается, я уже об этом [писал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287122/339911) :)