# Почему ruSO не поощряет дискуссии при ответе на вопрос, в споре же рождается истина?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, ответы, удаление-ответов

> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях

**Мне кажется решать должен задающий вопрос. Так как в первую очередь это он обратился за помощью**.

Зачем удалять-то ответы?

В дискуссиях может быть, конечно, и не полезная информация, но также там может быть и полезная информация.

Думаю, те, кому интересна эта информация, воспользуются ей! А те, кому нет, просто пройдут мимо!

**Хотелось бы услышать мнения других по этому поводу**.

И хотел бы предложить, чтобы ответы, которые собираются удалять, сохранялись хотя бы, у того кто задал вопрос (может раздел какой сделать?)

Я как новенький зашёл суда найти ответ! А мой вопрос не только поставили на закрытие, но и удалили то, что мне было интересно?

Не понятно почему???

Comment: И еще связанный: [Причины закрытия — “Вопрос-Опросник” vs “Однозначно верный ответ”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1629/186999)

Comment: @Grundy Первая ссылка о том  что ночевки будут натыкаться на кучу размышлений и не чего не поймут! А, вторая о том что я хочу сказать но не полностью и там нет ответа! Я же хотел бы узнать почему,  кто то не новенький и много всего знающий. Решает за новенького что он поймёт или не поймёт!И хотел бы предложить что бы ответы которые собираются удалять сохранялись хотя бы у того кто задал вопрос (может раздел какой сделать?) если уж так мозолят глаза всем! Так как лично мне один ответ нужен был а, его удалили!

Comment: _кто то не новенький и много всего знающий. Решает за новенького что он поймёт или не поймёт_ - потому что он не новенький и много всего знающий.

Comment: При достижении 10000 репутации можно смотреть удаленные вопросы и ответы. Свои удаленные вопросы и свои удаленные ответы можно смотреть всегда

Comment: @Grundy  Свои удаленные вопросы и свои удаленные ответы можно смотреть всегда.  Если не трудно то подскажите где. Я не нашёл.

Comment: Например, на вкладке _Активность_ в списках вопросов и ответов внизу есть ссылка: _недавно удаленные_. Кроме этого в поиске есть фильтр deleted: [Как найти свои удалённые сообщения?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5733/186999)

Comment: Под ответами, я имел ввиду комментарии не свои а, тех кто ответил на вопрос. Их удалили!

Comment: Я запутался: есть ответы, есть вопросы, есть комментарии под ответами и вопросами, что конкретно удалили и где? (ставь запятую _до_ союза `a`, а не после, тяжело читать твои сообщения)

Comment: @Grundy "Свои удаленные вопросы и свои удаленные ответы можно смотреть всегда" Не всегда, только если удалял их самостоятельно.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, на сколько я помню доступ к своим сообщениям ничем не ограничивается. Это где-то написано было или практическая проверка?

Comment: @Grundy практическая проверка, но наверное где-то написано тоже

Comment: @Grundy Да я сам уже запутался! Все только хают и не кто не чего не объясняет! Я задал вопрос. На него несколько раз ответили! Один ответ или два был не по теме, (просто нравоучение!) Я ответил на него! После чего вопрос поставили на закрытие или голосование, я до конца не понимаю ещё системы! вот вопрос -  WPF и ASP.NET только видео уроки на русском для C# . И те ответы (или комментарии не знаю как ещё сказать) которые мне лично были интересны удалили. Вот я и хотел узнать почему и зачем. Мне же как минимум инфа была полезна и я на неё рассчитывал!

Comment: @j.Atisto, [вот картинка](https://i.imgur.com/qAny5JI.png), что из какого блока было удалено?

Comment: @Grundy это то что оставили! А, то что удалили! Как раз то что меня и интересовало. В том то всё и дело!

Comment: @j.Atisto, удаленных ответов нет. Если речь про комментарии, то они могли нарушать правила сайта, поэтому и были удалены, подробнее могут сказать модераторы.

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Речь про комментарии! Если честно, это первый конкретный ответ по моему вопросу. Теперь осталось узнать какие такие правила они нарушили и всё.:) А, казалось бы, задал простой вопрос, получил ответ и на тебе! Нет не устраивает! (Извиняюсь за нервы!)

Comment: @j.Atisto, многие из удалённых комментариев нарушают правило сайта, но не то, о котором ты задал вопрос. Здесь запрещено обсуждать источники получения пиратских версий чего-либо.

Comment: @Qwertiy не в одном комментарии не было источника. А, только названия курсов.

Comment: @j.Atisto, источника не было, но обсуждение-то было. Я, как модератор, вижу, что удалено. Несколько комментариев даже восстановил. Кстати, названий конкретных курсов там тоже не было, только названия трёх сайтов, с которых эти курсы.

Comment: @Qwertiy но один то коммент оставили. С ссылкой  даже. Так в чём же разница. Ну можно указать к примеру что бы только  на официальные ресурсы указывали. Или отредактировать ссылку на официальную. Спасибо что восстановили коммент. Именно он мне и нужен был.

Comment: @Qwertiy "так как необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ." Так как вы модератор то вы же можете просто изменить вопрос как нужно. Так как я например, так и не понял как мне нужно задать вопрос что бы он всех устроил. Или хотя бы подсказки бы давали какие нибудь. Очень бы помогло, Да и как говорят шума было бы куда меньше. Ещё раз спасибо! за понимание.

Comment: @j.Atisto, в первом комментарии ссылка на ютьюб. Насколько я знаю, ютьюб сам удаляет нелицензионный контент, поэтому я считаю, что эта ссылка допустима. Впрочем, лицензионность конкретного видео я не проверял. Возможно, в этом месте я и не прав, но в таком случае, на мой взгляд, правильнее удалить ссылку, а не комментарий целиком.

Comment: @j.Atisto, нет, это стандартная причина. Поиск любых материалов считается оффтопиком. Для литературы есть вот такой список вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/178988, всё остальное закрывается. Про видеокурсы обсуждение было вот тут: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот с этим я полностью согласен.В данном случае мне не нужна была ссылка. Названия вполне хватило бы.

Comment: @Qwertiy по поводу (ссылок) этого я уже ниже писал и предложил вариант решения на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 7):

В цитате которую вы привели ключевым является

> Вопрос **порождает бесконечные прения** и дискуссии, **основанные** не на знаниях, а **на мнениях**

А если выжимать самую суть - бесконечные прения.

В таком споре рождается не только истина (у кого сторонников больше тот и победил), но еще и обиды. А что уж говорить о времени затраченном на отстаивание своей безусловно верной точки зрения. Вместо того чтобы помочь человеку с конкретной проблемой вы будете в сотый раз доказывать что, например, C# во всем превосходит Java.

Согласитесь, что польза для сообщества от подобных вопросов весьма сомнительна.

Перейдя по ссылкам на вопросы, оставленные в комментариях, можно увидеть что далеко не все вопросы на которые нельзя дать однозначно верный ответ будут закрыты.

Поэтому, если вы столкнулись с удалением ответа или закрытием вопроса, но не понимаете причин, то не стесняйтесь задавать вопрос здесь на Мете - более опытные участники сообщества пояснят причины произошедшего или восстановят справедливость в том случае, если ошибка все-таки была допущена.

---

Если желание поднять холиварную тему осталось, то заходите в одну из комнат [SO чатов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) и там поднимайте обсуждение, надеясь, что выбранная тема будет еще кому-то интересна.

Comment: Согласен с ответом и хотел бы добавить, что если истина и родится в результате такого спора, то, скорее всего, она потонет в информационном шуме самой дискуссии, что опять-таки сделает вопрос бесполезным для сообщества.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Не согласен. Так как тот кто ищет всегда найдет в этом шуме то что его интересует! Но с выше сказанным я тоже согласен хотя, я думаю нужно не ответ закрывать а, тех кто не по теме отвечает.

Comment: Согласен с ответом, но Java лучше, чем C#.

Comment: нет лучше или хуже! Для каждого лучшее своё! И вот именно из-за таких комментаторов и банят вопросы. Их комментарии и нужно удалять. Они бесполезны!

Comment: @j.Atisto Концепция SO - минимизировать шум и оставлять факты. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6963

Comment: @Nofate Ну, так и где же тут факты? Человек заходит, оставляет комментарий не по теме. А, когда говоришь ему об этом он тебя банит! Это ли справедливость! Я думаю если знаешь ответ ответь если нет, не лезь. И шума не будет и все довольны. А, так не польза , а вред получается. С этим и нужно бороться.

Comment: @j.Atisto человек оставил комментарий о том, что данный вопрос не соответсвует тематике SO. Вопрос закрыли не из-за того, что человек оставил комментарий, а из-за того что вопрос не соответствует тематике нашего сайта. Вопросы, которые являются тематическими для нас, описаны в справке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @j.Atisto и вас никто не банил. Это может сделать только модератор.

Comment: @Nofate Тематика моего вопроса абсолютно не противоречит SO. так как затрагивает вполне полезную тему для определённого круга  постояльцев SO и меня в том числе. И так как здесь много знающих людей, логично было бы спросить. Думал я!  Хорошие видео уроки  довольно сложно найти. Да и в правилах об этом нечего не сказано.  Я согласен что не всё знал, и много полезного прочитал пока мне отвечали. Что в очередной раз доказало что Дискуссия и полемика полезны.Видео контент очень актуальный сейчас. Да и  Ссылок не кто не давал, просто направили.Не думаю что это проблема.

Comment: А, вот данная тема думаю и в правду не к чему не приведёт. У всех своё мнение и с этим не чего не поделаешь.

Comment: @j.Atisto Поиск видеороликов не относится к: конкретной задаче программирования; инструментам для разработки;  проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных; настройке физических и виртуальных серверов; реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике. Вы думали, что вопрос соответствует тематике, но ошиблись. В этом нет ничего страшного: никакие санкции к вам никто не применяет.

Comment: Поскольку такие вопросы встречаются часто, а отвечать каждый раз одно и то же затруднительно, мы собрали информацию об учебных материалах в отдельный вопрос, поддерживаемый общими силами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584.

Comment: @Nofate здесь только о книгах,а автор ищет учебные видеоуроки. Честно говоря я тоже не понимаю почему список книг это вопрос подходящий под формат, а список видеоуроков по конкретному языку программированию - нет.

Comment: @FoggyFinder в аналогичных сборниках по питону и unity3d есть видеоуроки. То, почему присутствующее на RU.SO сообщество дотнетчиков не добавляет видеоуроки в общий сборник - это уже вопрос к ним. Но это не повод плодить "опросники".

Comment: @Nofate потому-что вопрос озаглавлен "Книги по C# и другая литература". Имеет смысл переименовать (и другие материалы) вопрос и закрывать опросники как дубликаты.

Comment: @FoggyFinder вполне разумное предложение.

Comment: @Nofate Но многие думают иначе: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3413/Нужны-ли-видеокурсы-в-списках-литературы-и-учебных-материалов

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сложность в том, что они там уже есть.

Comment: @Nofate♦ "опросники"??? Не кто не спрашивает какой кур лучше! Каждый пишет какой курс он считает хорошим. А, я как задавший вопрос выбиру подходящий для меня.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Именно по тому что на тему WPF и ASP.NET которой я интересовался очень мало материала на русском и именно по этому я решил задать этот вопрос. А, по поводу отделения хорошего контента от плохого, как писали в ссылке которую вы предоставили и должны смотреть модераторы. К примеру, если в комментариях указывается один видео курс к примеру 2 раза, то он считается вполне неплохим а, если 3 и более, то этот курс становиться лучшим по мнению большинства. Ну а если один раз , то можно вынести в отдельную ветку. Назвать к примеру (Курсы с 1  упоминаниями) или ещё как.

Comment: @j.Atisto а если указали 10 курсов по одному разу? Комментарии это не инструмент голосования, а модераторы могут не обладать нужными компетенциями, чтобы оценивать качество видеокурса (и модераторов всего пятеро, напомню).

Comment: @Nofate Ну и вынести их в такую же ветку как с литературой. А, компетенция не к чему. Можно просто при упоминании 3 и более раз помечать как хороший курс. Всё равно всем не угодишь, какая бы не была компетенция. А, раз 3 и более человек предложили значит это стоит внимания и всё. А, можно вообще скрипт какой написать. что бы автоматом это делал.

Comment: @j.Atisto "*Именно по тому что на тему WPF и ASP.NET которой я интересовался очень мало материала на русском*" - по данным темам завались материалов на русском языке. "*К примеру, если в комментариях указывается один видео курс к примеру 2 раза, то он считается вполне неплохим а, если 3 и более, то этот курс становиться лучшим по мнению большинства*" - вы перепутали, SO - не сайт для проведения голосований за лучший видеокурс. Создайте тему на форуме или в соцсети, если вам это нужно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight   В ссылке [https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3413/Нужны-ли-видеокурсы-в-списках-литературы-и-учебных-материалов] про обсуждение этого вопроса, была проблема как разделять хорошее от плохого вот я и предложил (2 там или три раза неважно)Это решило бы проблему и опять же не какого опросника я тут не вижу.Все го лишь мнение, о том какие курсы народ встретил. "Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов." А, что бы ими стать нужна как раз эта информация.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  Я думаю любая помощь важно. Согласен что я не совсем всю систему SO понимаю ещё. Какие то нюансы ещё не знаю. Но можно же придумать что то по продуктивнее чем удаление.

Comment: @Nofate: C# лучше, конечно :-P